# how to display underoot character in my vb6 dialog box

Tags: vb6, dialog, special-characters

I need to put a underoot symbol on dialog that i am creating in vb6 and i copy √ symbol from charactar map and when i paste it on the label in the dialog box a ? appears instead of the √ symbol. Any idea what should be done?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the font family of your dialog to the one that has the underroot symbol. For example the wingdings or other

Comment: tried wingdings is not the right, any idea what the right font is?

Comment: set your font family to arial and hold alt key and then type 251

Comment: or set font to Lucida Console

Comment: after setting font famil to arial, and pressing tab and when i enter number no input is accepted rather and nothing gets typed

Comment: i think you didn't read my comment properly. i asked to press the alt key

Its the key next to space bar key. usually under 'x'.

Comment: i think i know what is a alt key. i did exactly that. and held alt key as i typed 251 but it did not work

Comment: using numeric keypad press alt and 251 and it works not the number key above characters. if using latop then press fucntion key and find numeric key over alphabet keys